# Pause SpriteKit game with Physics SKSpriteNode child

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics, skspritenode, skphysicsworld

I have a SKSpriteNode with a dynamic physics body on a `SKNode *_fgLayer`.

Now, when I pause or unpause the game I want that SKSpriteNode to remain in place and not rotate or fall down. If I simply use `_fgLayer.paused = YES;` the SKSpriteNode does not stay in place but rather rotates and falls down. If I set `physicsBody.dynamic = NO;` when paused and         `physicsBody.dynamic = YES;` when unpaused it works.

However, after a few tries I always get the following crash:

`"Assertion failed: (typeA == b2_dynamicBody || typeB == b2_dynamicBody), function SolveTOI, file /SourceCache/PhysicsKit/PhysicsKit-4.6/PhysicsKit/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp, line 670."`

So, I guess setting a `physicsBody.dynamic = NO;` and back does not work.

Does anyone have an idea of
**how to pause dynamic physics bodies to remain in place when the game is paused?**

Comment: I think you should use sprite.speed = 0.0 here.

Comment: Or try setting scene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.0 ( https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/speed )

Comment: UPDATE: A workaround is to make all the aspects that affect the node from the phsyicsBody to remain stable. I used the following code to pause and something similar for the unpause: _fish.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    _fish.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    _fish.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    _fish.physicsBody.angularVelocity = 0;

Comment: scene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.0 did the job well! Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try setting your physicsWorld.speed to 0.0:

```
scene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.0
```

[Apple SKPhysicsWorld Ref](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsWorld_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsWorld/speed).

Comment: How do you resume later? What speed to you reset to when you want to resume?

Comment: My bad, I just had a read of the apple's Documentation. One can set scene.physicsWorld.speed = 1.0 to resume. 1 indicates the normal speed, 2 will be twice as fast as the normal speed.

Answer (score 3):

Setting scene.view.paused = YES works for me - specially when there are actions running on the child node.

`self.scene.view setPaused:YES`